# Enable automatic power management of NVIDIA graphics card on headless server?

Tags: drivers, server, nvidia, headless

My NVIDIA card seems to be using the full performance mode even when running a headless server:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Oct  5 11:10:47 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.57.02    Driver Version: 470.57.02    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 50%   50C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /   979MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to make the card instead use adaptive throttling and throttle down in this case.

How can I achieve this? Since this is a headless server I can't use graphical utilities to control the cards behavior (e.g. installing nvidia-settings pulls in the whole world).

Comment: Nothing in this question tells me it is a Ubuntu server.

Comment: Since it's a question about servers on askubuntu you can assume it's a question about Ubuntu servers.

Comment: No many ask off topic questions that then get deleted. Never assume.